# How to elegantly convert a long string of dates into dym format?

Tags: r, date

I have a column of date (column type is "character") that looks like this:

```
X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.06
X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.13
X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.20
X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.27
...
```

Is there an elegant way to convert these dates into the format YYYY-MM-DD as "date" type?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the prefix until the 'End.' and it should work with `ymd`

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df1$date <- ymd(str_remove(df1$date, ".*End\\."))
df1$date
#[1] "2019-01-06" "2019-01-13" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-27"
```

---

Or use `as.Date` from `base R`

```
as.Date(df1$date, format = "X1Wk.End.%Y.%b.%d")
#[1] "2019-01-06" "2019-01-13" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-27"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.06", "X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.13", 
"X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.20", "X1Wk.End.2019.Jan.27")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```